# Replacing random characters in string

Tags: python, string, loops, random, replace

I have a random string word for example

```
word = graphic
```

I want to take this word and and turn any random letters into underscore and put space in between

for the output to look something like this

g _ a _ h _ c

The underscore should be random for a different word each time. How can I do this efficiently

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this using Python's built-in random module. The idea here is to randomly select indices of the letters in the word to be replaced by an underscore.

```
import random

def random_underscores(word, p=0.5):
    """
    Function to replace letters in a word with underscores at random places.
    
    Parameters:
    word: str, the word to replace letters in.
    p: float, probability of each character being replaced. Default is 0.5.
    """

    
    return ' '.join('_' if random.random() < p else char for char in word)

word = "graphic"
print(random_underscores(word))
```

This script defines a function random_underscores() that takes in a word and a probability p (default is 0.5, so on average half of the characters will be replaced).

The function uses a list comprehension to iterate over each character in the word. For each character, it generates a random number between 0 and 1, and if that number is less than p, it replaces the character with an underscore.

You can adjust the value of p to control the average number of letters that get replaced. A value of 1.0 will replace all letters, and a value of 0.0 will replace none.

Remember that because the replacement is random, you'll get different results each time you run the function with the same inputs.

If you want to ensure that at least one character is always visible, you can modify the function slightly to check if all characters have been replaced. If so, it can randomly select one character to remain visible:

```
import random

def random_underscores(word, p=0.5):
    """
    Function to replace letters in a word with underscores at random places, ensuring at least one character remains.
    
    Parameters:
    word: str, the word to replace letters in.
    p: float, probability of each character being replaced. Default is 0.5.
    """
    replaced = ['_' if random.random() < p else char for char in word]

    # Check if all characters have been replaced. If so, randomly select one to remain
    if all(char == '_' for char in replaced):
        replaced[random.randint(0, len(word)-1)] = word[random.randint(0, len(word)-1)]
        
    return ' '.join(replaced)

word = "graphic"
print(random_underscores(word))
```

Comment: No need for the list comprehension, `join()` will take a generator.

Comment: You can use like this- return ' '.join('_' if random.random() < p else char for char in word)

Comment: Edit your answer to change that, instead of using a comment.

Comment: @Barmar join is marginally more efficient if you use a list comp

Comment: @Jab Good point, I guess it can calculate the output size first instead of growing incrementally.

Comment: Ty this works but sometimes it will return just blank underscore, do you know why?

Comment: @user12128587 There's nothing preventing it from randomly choosing `_` for every character.

Comment: Is there a way to add something to prevent it? @Barmar

Comment: @user12128587 - The reason for that is due to the randomness involved in the selection of characters to be replaced by underscores. In the given code, the probability for each character to be replaced is independent and set by the parameter p.

If p is set to a high value (close to 1), then it becomes very likely that each character will be replaced, which may result in all characters being replaced and you only see underscores.

I am adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helps you

```py
from random import choice
word = "helloWorld"
word = "".join(["_" if choice([True, False]) else char for char in word])
print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from random import randint
def RandUnder(word):
  nofUnderscores = randint(1, len(word))
  for i in range(nofUnderscores):
    randPos = randint(0, len(word)-1)
    word[randPos] = "_"
  return word
word = "example"
print(" ".join(RandUnder(list(word))))
```